# using Tail and Grep to select a specific phrase within a double quotation

Tags: linux, shell, logging, grep, tail

currently I am `tail` and `grep` a live log but would like to `grep` the entire url within the double quotation ...

Current tail i've put together

```
tail -F trans.log | grep --color -E -i "https://www.example.com|$"
```

Log

```
1.1.1.1 6 - [21/Jan/2022:16:41:21 +0000] "GET /media/catalog/product/cache/####.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 - "https://www.example.com/customer/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
```

Desired output:

for grep `https://www.example.com/customer/` would be highlighted during the live log Tail

Comment: May be: `grep --color -ioE 'https://www\.example\.com[^"]*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this command:

```sh
tail -F trans.log | grep --color -ioE 'https://www\.example\.com[^"]*'
```

Pattern `https://www\.example\.com[^"]*` matches a substring starting with `https://www.example.com` followed by 0 or more non-`"` characters.